# How to get value on one field based on two different fields

Tags: odoo

So Im creating a hotel management module . I have the option to filter rooms based on bed_type and tag. Tag contains different facilities like AC, TV etc. So an user will come and select a bed_type and the facilities he wants and in the third field it should show the rooms that have the given  configuration if not available an error messages should come. SO i created a onchange function to do this , but i dint know how to include the tags in it. Im doing it on odoo v14. m

This is the model for the room

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _


class HotelRoom(models.Model):
_name = 'hotel.room'
_description = 'hotel room'
_rec_name = 'room_number'


room_number = fields.Char('Room Number', required=True)

room_rent = fields.Monetary('Room Rent')
tag = fields.Many2many('hotel.tags', string='Facilities')

dormitory_count = fields.Integer('Dormitory count')

bed_type = fields.Selection([
    ('single', 'Single'),
    ('double', 'Double'),
    ('dormitory', 'Dormitory')
], required=True, default='other')
```

This is the model for the reception

```
class HotelAccommodation(models.Model):
    _name = 'accommodation.room'
    _description = 'Reception'

        
bed_type = fields.Selection([
    ('single', 'Single'),
    ('double', 'Double'),
    ('dormitory', 'Dormitory')
], required=True, string= 'Bed type')

state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft','Draft'),
    ('check-in','Check-In'),
    ('check-out', "Check-Out"),
    ('cancel','Cancel'),

], required=True, default='draft', tracking=True)

tag = fields.Many2many('hotel.tags', string='Facilities')

 room_id = fields.Many2one('hotel.room', string='Room')
```

Using this I can filter the rooms based on the bed_type but I need to have the tags as well.I tried giving it inside the domain but its not working .

```
@api.onchange('bed_type')
def filter_room(self):
    for rec in self:
        return {'domain': {'room_id': [('bed_type', '=', rec.bed_type)]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also to add the `tag` field to the domain and to the `onchange` decorator, so the method will be called when the tag field is modified.

The method is invoked on a pseudo-record that contains the values present in the form, you do not need to loop over self.

Try the following example:

```
@api.onchange('bed_type', 'tag')
def filter_room(self):
    return {'domain': {'room_id': [('bed_type', '=', self.bed_type), ('tag', 'in', self.tag.ids)]}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added a selection field in the model that is " state " . So I can know if a room is checked or not. So I edited the code this way.    But its not working                                                                                      @api.depends('state')
    @api.onchange('bed_type', 'tag')
    def filter_room(self):
        for room in self:
            return {'domain': {'room_id': [('bed_type', '=', self.bed_type), ('tag', 'in', self.tag.ids),
                                           ('state', 'not in', ['check-in'])]}}

Comment: You do not need the `depends` decorator. You added a `state` field in the ``hotel.room`` model and to filter rooms based on that field, all you have to do is to update the return domain in the ``onchange`` method. Add ``('state', 'not in', ['check-in'])`` to the returned domain in my answer above, and it should work.

Comment: It seems I made a mistake in editing the code. The state field is actually created in the second model " accommodation.room" . So I used the depends decorator.

Comment: It is working now , I corrected the code .

Answer (score 0):

You can use _compute fields with the store option = True

take a look https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields